# Jersey client downloads content partially

Tags: java, web-services, security, spring-boot, jersey

I have a Java Jersey client with which I connect to a server and download an image like this:

```
   WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
   Response response = webTarget.request().get();
```

The client response is the following:

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=resourceURL, status=200, reason=OK}}
```

When I try to parse the body as an InputStream like this to a file

```
InputStream imageInputStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.jpg"));

int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

outputStream.close();
```

The input stream breaks at ~7000bytes and the content never gets parsed totally.

I have no access to the image server, and if I try to access the URL of the image in the browser, it works and the image gets downloaded.

On top the server has a self signed SSL certificate which I registered to my java keystore, can that be also part of the issue?

Comment: What does the Content-Length header say?

Comment: @peeskillet the content length is not the image size but the ~7000 bytes. More specifically 7194 bytes.

Comment: Can you specify real Image service link you're using?